# AWS beanstalk monitoring metrics disappear during deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

We have setup an immutable configuration for AWS beanstalk using both web and worker classes (multiple clusters). When we deploy a new application, it creates a temporary autoscaling group and then deploys to that and in end switches back to the old autoscaling group. This process takes about 20-30 mins and works fine.

Although, every time we deploy the application the monitoring stats: CPU utilization, Memory utilization, disk space and so on, all disappear for 5-6 hours before returning back. Seems like an AWS issue but not sure if we are doing anything wrong. Has anyone else experience such behavior? Is there a workaround?

EDIT:
Here's the screenshot for missing memory metric, as you can see there was no data between 5.30pm and 11.30pm.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this issue in future - I figured out the issue. The script I am using is provided by Cloudwatch that internally caches the auto-scaling group name for 6 hours. Typically that would not be an issue, since these values do not change regularly. But due to immutable deploy a temporary auto-scaling group is created during deploy that gets cached for 6 hours.

To resolve this, I replaced the following line in the CloudWatchClient code:

```
$meta_data_short_ttl = 21600; # 6 hours
```

with:

```
meta_data_short_ttl = 600; # 10 mins
```

Can also be done via `.ebextension` change from existing code if you are using [this script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-cw.html):

```
04-reduce-cache:
    command: sed -i 's/meta_data_short_ttl = 21600; # 6 hours/meta_data_short_ttl = 600; # 10 mins/g' /opt/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/CloudWatchClient.pm
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **replicate** the issue using load-balanced EB environment with one instance by checking `CPUUtilization`.

I observed a **small gap** (10 minutes) after  the immutable deployment. Which is far from 5-6 hours.

The observed delay was **only in EB console**. There was **no delay** in the corresponding CloudWatch (CW) metrics. Thus I could monitor the `CPUUtilization` in the CW while waiting for EB console to catch up.

For my tests I performed **two immutable deployments**. And in CW, the metrics align nicely (without any gaps) for the new instances created by the deployments:

[image]

Metrics for your instances should also be viable in CW. Thus you should be able to view them there, while EB consoles catches up.

To get the **unified view** of all the individual metrics, one can use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html):

```
AVG(METRICS())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I have been capturing metrics from autoscale group instead of the average from instances. Did you see the metrics for autoscale group?

Comment: @Ankit I haven't looked at the ASG metrics. The ASG metrics in CW also have gaps?

Comment: yes I'm using ASG as that helps keep cumulative metrics when instances go in and out of the system. I posted the screenshot in my question, as you can see that the Memory metric had a gap of 6 hours even though the deploy finished in ~30 mins.

Comment: @Ankit I can check this. Memory requires CW agent, unlike CPU. You setup EB with it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CW agent out of the box

Comment: @Ankit I see. I will try to check it out.

Comment: sorry I'm actually using this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-cw.html